# Odoo: still get no module name phonenumbers

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm trying to install Asterisk dial2call in my Odoo V8.
First try , Odoo gave: "Unable to install module "base_phone" because an external dependency is not met: No module named phonenumbers". Then 
I installed phonenumbers using `pip install phonenumbers` in windows prompt command.

My problem is, even restarting my server, Odoo 8 still doesn't recognize phonenumbers dependencies.

Comment: just try to import phonenumbers with python only just test it your self

Comment: open python IDLE type import phonenumbers if it's ok then you installed the package correctly

Comment: It's ok with Python IDLE using  import phonenumbers. Why Odoo doesn't recognize it?

Comment: how did you install odoo is it with .exe

Comment: Yes with the .exe (package installer)

Comment: i think you should copy the package installed in the python27/lib/site-package from you python to the folder of the odoo 8 you should find site-pckage also there because odoo 8 is not using the python that you installed

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i can't see site-package in odoo 8.

Comment: Just search for the folder contains lxml .... And other package that odoo install

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. i needed to add it to Program Files (x86)\Odoo 8.0-20170320\server

Comment: You welcome my friend